# Difference between "as part of" and "in the context of"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

At work, we often have to send email broadcasts that need to be in both English and French. My colleague usually prepares the French text and I prepare the English one (or translate hers). Later, we each read both versions.

She's learning English and sometimes she asks me questions about the words I use, their meanings, conjugations etc.

Since I am not a native English speaker, I often have to look those things up to explain the differences but this time I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Here's the example:

- "**As part of** the move planned for 1 September 2020, the department provided you with ..."

My colleague asked me if this wouldn't be better :

- "**In (the) context of** the move planned for 1 September 2020, the department provided you with ..."

I would say that this works as well but, for this example, I am still inclined to go with "As part of". I think that there's a slight difference between the two, which, however, I am not able to explain.

Could you please tell which one's (more) correct, the difference between the two and if there's a completely different way you would start that sentence?

Note: This is my first post and I am not sure if this is the right forum for my question. Please let me know if I should change forums.

Comment: *As part of* addresses one detail of many. *In the context of* usually means a framework around the detail addressed. One phrase points down while the other points up.

Comment: *In the context of* doesn't mean the same thing as *as part of*. So, no. It wouldn't be better. If you need to rephrase it (and I don't see why you do), you could use **for the purpose of** instead. (That, too, doesn't mean quite the same thing, but it's more relevant than the other suggestion.)

Comment: Thank you @JasonBassford
No, I don't need to rephrase it. My colleague just wanted to know if it would be possible to use *In the context of*.

Comment: Thank you as well @YosefBaskin
Could you please just give me an example related to a move where one could use *In the context of*?

Comment: *In the context of keeping our friendship, I went along to the horror film*. *In the context of all that vulgarity, the word 'hell' seemed mild*. *In the context of the move, coming in 10 minutes late was forgivable*.